# How to add a class to a menu item that has children (nested pages) in Django-CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm working on a project where there's some specific styling on a menu item which has nested children. The menu structure looks something like this

```
Home
|
About
|
Services
|_ web design
|_ social marketing
|_ traditional marketing
```

I'm using {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "menu.html" %} in my template and I have the following inside my menu.html:

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for child in children %}
<li class="{% if child.selected %}active{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %}dropdown{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
    {% if child.children %}
    <ul>
        {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I put {% if child.sibling %}dropdown{% endif %} in there to illustrate where I want the class to be added, but targeting it as a child.sibling is not the right way of doing it. Is there a way to target the specific dropdown like this {% if child.has_children %}dropdown{% endif %}?

Thanks

Comment: Does `{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}` do what you want?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I tried child.sibling, child.ancestor, child.descendant, and none of them work - except child.sibling, but it's adding the dropdown class to every menu item except the child.selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{% if child.children %}...{% endif %}`

Comment: No idea why it works now. I tried that earlier, but it didn't work..
THANKS A LOT!!